# Public class with a private functions by default

Tags: swift

I have a public class with a multiple private properties and private functions. For each private element of the class I have to add private access modifier.

Is it possible to set up a multiple properties and functions to private in a  public class with a minimal use of "private" keyword?

```
class Car {

  var property: String
  private var property1: String
  private var property2: String
  private var property3: String

  func action()
  private func actionA()
  private func actionB()
  private func actionC()

}
```

Comment: Technically the access level for that class is "internal", meaning that it can be accessed inside the module it's defined in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanted to you could use the following for properties:

```
private var property1: String, property2: String
```

You can't do the same for methods. Maybe one day this will be supported:

```
private extension Car {
  func action() {}
}
```